# BPM suite installation on Jboss FUSE (instead of EAP)

Tags: jboss, business-process-management, jbossfuse

I am looking to install Jboss BPM suite on Jboss fuse instead of usual EAP servers. Please help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more details on what you already tried and what are your errors?

Have you read/try the documentation?
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Installation_Guide/Integration.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-fuse/6.3/paged/integration-guide/

Regards,

Comment: I have gone through the integration guide what I am actually looking for is installing BPM web console as well on Jboss Fuse server? The container I am looking to use is Karaf(not EAP).